# "There are still problems" vs. "there still are problems"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order

> - There are still problems.
> - There still are problems.

Is one word order more correct than the other and do they have identical meaning?

Comment: The latter is an emphasized variant and the former is ordered neutrally, but this could be more fittingly answered at the English Language Learners stack exchange http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=adverb+position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is the normal order. The second might be used to strongly contradict a previous statement. In that case the verb would be stressed: *There still ARE problems*.

Answer (score 1):

Same meaning. "There still are problems" is more correct if "still" is an adverb.